# How to export multiple classes in typescript node.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript, module, export

I have been struggling with some errors importing classes into node app.js.

```
import {Class} from "./path/to/Class.ts"
```

The above code gives me the following error.

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I even tried adding "type":"module" to package.json but still no Success.

My Package Organization:

[image]

Backend Package.json:

[image]

tsconfig.json

[image]

Comment: When do you get the error? Is it when running a file with Node or is it during Typescript compilation? Could you post the contents of the other package.json as well?

Comment: I get error when i run “node app.ts”

Comment: The node command can't run .ts files directly, you need to compile the .ts files to .js with the tsc command and then run those e.g. node app.js. Or you could install ts-node which allows you to run a .ts file. Let me know if that works out

Comment: Actually i have tried it "node app.js" now but its giving me "Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module:" now

Comment: I think you need to change the ```.mts``` extension to ```.ts``` on InstantMessageServer because ```tsc``` doesn't compile that to ```.mjs``` as far as I know. Also remove the ```"type": "module"``` from ```package.json``` in this case. This worked for me when I recreated your project structure and tested it.

Comment: Okay thanks , let me try and i will get back to you

Comment: Hi Zwiers , thanks for your time , my issue is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Okay , with the help of  Zwiers Comment , i solved the issue. i actually had to remove "type":"module" from the package.json file